# XSLT: templates without mode ignored in result-documents

Tags: xslt, mode

I'm learning to use the mode attribute and must being doing something wrong. Apologies if this has been answered before but I'm not finding it here.

I want to process "title" elements separately depending on their context. For the main document, I want to add an "a" element inside of it:

```
    <xsl:template match="title">
     <div>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <a href="some_URL">some text
      </a>
     </div>
    </xsl:template>
```

But elsewhere I'm creating result-documents where I just want the title:

```
    <xsl:tamplate match="title" mode="print">
     <div class="title">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </div>
    </xsl:template>
```

In my main template match="/" I'm doing a for-each for each section, creating a result-document for each one:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="/topic/body/bodydiv/section">
     <xsl:result-document href="{$printoutfile}">
     <html><head>some stuff</head><body>
     <div class="section">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="print"/>
     </div>
     ... more stuff...
     </body</html>
     </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Then I call everything else for the main document:

```
    <html><head>stuff</head>
    <body>
     <div>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The problem is this works for the result-document title but none of the rest of the result-document templates are used, since they don't have mode="print" on them. So the rest of the result-document all comes out as text.

Any idea what I need to do here? I'm obviously missing something basic.

thank you
Scott

Comment: You have not shown any of the other templates but if you expect the `xsl:apply-templates mode="print"/>` to apply them then you need to have a `mode="#all"` on them. And if they do aditional `apply-templates` then you need to use `<xsl:apply-templates select="#current"/>`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#modes for details.

Comment: That works nicely, thank you! I am getting an error message however:

        IDW0713E: XTRE0540: Ambiguous rule match for /topic/body[1]/bodydiv[2]/section[1]/title[1]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Let's solve one issue in one question. I have put my comment's suggestion into an answer so that we can close down this question as being solved. For the other problem ask a new question, unless of course your XSLT processor tells you which two or more templates match that `title` element and you can simply solve it by deciding which one has more priority and putting e.g. `priority="5"` on it.

Comment: That'll do it, thank you for solving my problem. -- Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not shown any of the other templates but if you expect the `<xsl:apply-templates mode="print"/>` to apply them then you need to have a `mode="#all"` on them. And if they do additional apply-templates then you need to use `<xsl:apply-templates select="#current"/>`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#modes for details.